# MySQL retrieve variable from Stored Procedure in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've seen this question asked a load of times, but they're all really long, and I just can't get my head around what they're doing ... So, could someone tell me how to get the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from this procedure into php using PDO:

## Table:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

## Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `simpleProcedure`(newname varchar(50), OUT returnid INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES (newname);
    SET returnid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

## PHP code I've tried:

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("CALL simpleProcedure(:name,:returnid)");
$stmt->bindValue(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':returnid',$returnid,PDO::PARAM_INT,11);
$stmt->execute();
echo $returnid;
```

But, probably obvious to  someone who has more brain cells than me, this doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

## Reference as to why I believe this SHOULD work:

http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements (Example #4)

Comment: You probably want to use bindparam instead of bindvalue. bindparam takes a variable by reference which would allow the statement to set the value back into the variable. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Yep, tried that, didn't work

Comment: So, with the `bindParam` it seems to be trying to work, as I now don't get the `$returnid not set` error ... But it still doesn't `echo` anything

Comment: In the manual it says: `length: Length of the data type. To indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the length.`

Comment: Nope ... That didn't work either ... I've updated my post to reflect what I have tried

Comment: instead of doing an `echo`, try doing a `var_dump` on `$returnid`. Then you can see what the actual value is instead of nothing. Also try defining `$returnid` to an initial value (0/-1) and see if that changes anything. Also, reading through the comments on the bindparam page I saw this [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#109791). Also, you do know there is a [pdo::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) method right?

Comment: I did some more investigation about this issue. It goes back to 2005! Here are the references to the bug reports: [Original from 2005 - 2013](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11638). The new bug report and discussion: [to the present](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69206).

Comment: Yep ... Unfortunately, I believe you are right Ryan. D'you wanna stick it in as an answer :( ... I hate bugs ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug that has been going on for a long time... since 2005!

Here is the original bug report: [2005 through to 2013](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11638). And here is the new bug report: [From 2013 to the present](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69206).

There are various approaches to getting the answer returned, I found one of them and demonstrate it...

The 'trick' is that to get the output from a 'mysql' procedure. It is a 'two stage' process.

- The first part is to run the procedure with your inputs, and also tell it what MYSQL variables to store the result in.
- Then, you run a separate query to 'select' those 'mysql' variables.

It is described quite clearly here: [php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/)

*Update (Jan 2017):*

Here is an example showing the use of variables for 'IN', 'INOUT' and 'OUT' Mysql procedure parameters.

Before we start here are some tips:

- When developing: Run PDO in 'emulates mode' as it is more reliable at determining errors in the procedure call.
- Only bind PHP variables to the procedure 'IN' parameters.

You will get some really odd runtime errors when you try binding variables to INOUT and OUT parameters.

As usual I tend to provide rather more comments than are required ;-/

*Runtime Environment (XAMPP):*

- PHP: 5.4.4
- Mysql: 5.5.16

*Source Code:*

- [SQL Procedure](http://pastebin.com/SzcPNBm1)
- [PHP with output](http://pastebin.com/RSGDD2it)

#### SQL Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `demoSpInOutSqlVars`(IN     pInput_Param  INT, /* PHP Variable will bind to this*/   
                                      /* --- */  
                                      INOUT  pInOut_Param  INT, /* contains name of the SQL User variable that will be read and set by mysql */
                                      OUT    pOut_Param    INT) /* contains name of the SQL User variable that will be set by mysql */
BEGIN
    /*
     * Pass the full names of SQL User Variable for these parameters. e.g. '@varInOutParam'
     * These 'SQL user variables names' are the variables that Mysql will use for:
     *    1) finding values
     *    2) storing results
     *
     * It is similar to 'variable variables' in PHP.  
     */
     SET pInOut_Param      := ABS(pInput_Param) + ABS(pInOut_Param); /* always positive sum  */
     SET pOut_Param        := ABS(pInput_Param) * -3;                /* always negative * 3  */ 
END$$
```

#### PHP Code:

*DB Connection:*

```
$db = appDIC('getDbConnection', 'default'); // get the default db connection
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);    
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Note: The output is the same with `EMULATE_PREPARES` = false.

*Set all PHP Variables that will be used:*

```
$phpInParam     = 5;                  
$phpInOutParam  = 404;          /* PHP InOut variable  ==> read and should be changed  */
$phpOutParam    = null;         /* PHP Out   variable  ==> should be changed           */
```

*Define and Prepare the SQL procedure call:*

```
$sql = "call demoSpInOut(:phpInParam, 
                         @varInOutParam, /* mysql variable name will be read and updated */
                         @varOutParam)"; /* mysql variable name that will be written to  */

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

*Bind PHP Variables and Set SQL Variables:*

- 1) bind the PHP variables

  $stmt->bindParam(':phpInParam', $phpInParam, PDO::PARAM_INT);
- 2) Set the SQL User INOUT variables

  $db->exec("SET @varInOutParam = $phpInOutParam"); // This is safe as it just sets the value into the MySql variable.

*Execute the procedure:*

```
$allOk = $stmt->execute();
```

*Get the SQL Variables into the PHP variables:*

```
$sql = "SELECT @varInOutParam AS phpInOutParam,
               @varOutParam   AS phpOutParam
        FROM dual";
$results = current($db->query($sql)->fetchAll());

$phpInOutParam = $results['phpInOutParam'];
$phpOutParam   = $results['phpOutParam'];
```

Note: maybe not the best way ;-/

*Display the PHP variables*

```
"$phpInParam:"     => "5"
"$phpInOutParam:"  => "409"
"$phpOutParam:"    => "-15"
```

Comment: But this isn't using the `OUT` function as it should be used, as described in: http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements (Example #4). If I was going to use another `SEELCT` statement, I may aswel change the procedure to have `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS returnid` instead of `SET returnid = LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score -2):

let me preface this by saying it's a guess, as I NEVER use prepared statements...

typically you don't bind your return val, you do this

```
$status = $statement->execute(  );

$resultArray = $statement->fetchAll( );
$statement->closeCursor( );
if (!is_array($resultArray)) {
    return array();
}
return $resultArray[0]['returnid'];
```

take it with a grain of salt...

Comment: Nah, that returns with `undefined index` error :( ... But, for your troubles, here's a picture of some little ducks skateboarding ... http://www.vhsmag.com/blog/v/images/001751145.jpg