# SQL procedure with inout param and pdo not working

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have procedure with an INOUT param. When I call the procedure from within phpMyAdmin it works nice, althought I don't see the value of the INOUT param later, as I would when using only OUT.

Now, I try to call this procedure from php using PDO:

```
$query = "CALL setSessionId(:user_id, :session_id);";
$statement = $this->database->prepare($query);

$statement->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
$statement->bindParam(':session_id', $session_id, PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);

$session_id = "test";
echo "<p>before: $session_id</p>";
$statement->execute();

echo "<p>afterwards: $session_id</p>";
```

[PDOStatement::bindParam documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php) says you don't need to fetch anything after `execute` when using an `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` but the `session_id` doesn't end up being in the database and isn't updated after execute.

If I change `session_id` to an IN only parameter and add an extra OUT parameter which I fetch after `execute` it works.

Comment: Maybe interesting? [MySQL retrieve variable from Stored Procedure in PHP PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445)

Comment: OK so I should better not use an INOUT param although it would shorten the parameters?

Comment: Yeah OK then I will have to live with 8 params instead of 4 in one of my procedures^^ Thank you.

Comment: I'll just use a `SELECT updatedValue FROM updatedTable;` like before^^ I just thought, since they offer these kind of parameters it would be cool to use them.