# Is there a way to get an OUT parameter from a Stored Procedure using PDO in one single call?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Here's my code. It takes two inputs and has one output. Currently I have to `CALL` the Stored Procedure, and then I have to make a `SELECT` against the output to get the value. Is there a way to get the output *without* that addition `SELECT` at that end? I'm trying to make the code as compact and efficient as possible.

I want to stick with named parameters as much as possible and stay away from using `?`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL Sellers_Test(:username, :barcode, @output)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':barcode', $barcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor();
$output = $conn->query("SELECT @output AS output")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo 'procedure returned '.$output['output'].'<p>';
```

Comment: Did you try binding it, eg `$stmt->bindParam(':output', $output, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);`. See [example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1038)

Comment: No, I didn't realize that was an option. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Didn't work when I changed @output to :output and added your code. `Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine Sellers_Test is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger`

Comment: Might need the length arg like the PHP manual example. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: I suspect that part of PDO is broken. maybe interesting? [MySQL retrieve variable from Stored Procedure in PHP PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445)

Comment: I would not be too concerned about the speed of the second fetch as everything is already in memory so the impact is minimal.