# PHP value of stored function SQL

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, pdo, stored-functions

we can `fetch` result of `PDO` with a `stored procedure` like that

```
$pdo = <PDO class>

//Request
$request = $pdo->prepare("CALL `procedure1`(:arg1, :arg2)");
$request->execute(
    [
        'arg1' => $arg1,
        'arg2' => $arg2
    ]
);
$values = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but i don't know how to `fetch` or get the result of `stored function` that returns `true`/`false` or `BIGINT`/`VARCHAR`

```
$pdo = <PDO class>

//Request
$request = $pdo->prepare("CALL `function1`(:arg1)");
$request->execute(
    [
        'arg1' => $arg1
    ]
);

$result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // ERROR
$result = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["function1"]; // ERROR
```

I get an empty value

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445

Comment: Use 'select' instead. e.g. "SELECT  `function1`(:arg1) AS funcResult"