# PDO::fetchAll not working with MySQL stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm trying to return a row from a database by calling a stored procedure throught PHP. However, when I do this how I normally would I get a "General Error".

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Skilaverkefni 4\Courses\read.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Skilaverkefni 4\Courses\read.php(11): PDOStatement->fetchAll(2)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Skilaverkefni 4\index.php(13): ReadCourse('FOR3L3U')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Skilaverkefni 4\Courses\read.php on line 11
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

    function ReadCourse($courseID)
    {

        require "dbCon.php";
        $SQL = "SET @p0='" . $courseID . "'; CALL ReadCourse(@p0);";
        echo "$SQL";
        $logon = $pdo->prepare($SQL);
        $logon->execute();
        $records = $logon->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        print_r($records);

    }



?>
```

After a long Google-session I found out that the issue is most caused by the way I'm handling the reading of the data returned from the stored procedure, how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of PDO is to make it impossible to run any old database query you choose to pass as a string.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
<?php
/* Call a stored procedure with an INOUT parameter */
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL puree_fruit(?)');
$sth->bindParam(1, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();
print("After pureeing fruit, the colour is: $colour");
?>
```

Comment: FYI, with mysql inout parameters do not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445