# PHP: How to get the output value of a MySql Stored Procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I try to get the output value of a MySQL stored procedure with PHP. I found some similar questions here on StackOverflow, but none of them helped.

Based on my researches, I found two ways of how to achieve this goal, however, none of them worked so far. The procedure's output is simply not caught, no matter how I tried.

---

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**

In the following case, I set *AAA* as the default value for the variable `@name`, then I pass it as a parameter to the stored procedure `jani()`. In the procedure, I change the value of the in-output variable to *BBB*, so I expect the passed *AAA* to be changed to *BBB*. Then I select the variable and try to display the result value, however, the value remains *AAA*.

My code:

```
// DEFINING THE PROCEDURE:
$sql = '
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS jani;
    CREATE PROCEDURE jani (
        INOUT output            VARCHAR(3)
    )
    BEGIN

        SET @output = "BBB";
    END';
$oDb->exec($sql);



// DEFINING THE VARIABLE TO CATCH THE OUTPUT:
$sql = 'SET @name = "AAA"';
$do = $oDb->prepare($sql);
$do->execute();



// CALLING THE PROCEDURE AND TRYING TO CATCH THE OUTPUT:    
$sql = 'CALL jani(@name)';
$do = $oDb->prepare($sql);
$do->execute();



// SELECTING THE (HOPEFULLY UPDATED) VARIABLE:
$sql = 'SELECT @name name';
$do = $oDb->prepare($sql);
$do->execute();



// DISPLAYING THE RESULT:
var_dump($do->fetchObject());
```

---

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

I also followed tutorials like [this here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.php.doc/doc/t0023502.html) without success. The source claims that `$do->bindParam()` should work, but it did not help in my case. The value of the variable is still unchanged. My code implementing the second solution:

```
// DEFINING THE PROCEDURE:
$sql = '
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS jani;
    CREATE PROCEDURE jani (
        INOUT output            VARCHAR(3)
    )
    BEGIN

        SET @output = "BBB";
    END';
$oDb->exec($sql);



// SETTING DEFAULT VARIABLE VALUE:
$name = 'AAA';



// CALLING THE PROCEDURE AND BINDING THE VARIABLE TO ITS PARAMETER:
$sql = 'CALL jani(?)';
$do = $oDb->prepare($sql);
$do->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 3);
$do->execute();



// DISPLAYING THE RESULT (which is still "AAA" unfortunately):
echo $name;
```

Both cases return the unmodified value *AAA* instead of the procedure output *BBB*. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all the helping comments and answers :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Why not put it in a single query ??? `$sql = 'SET @name = "AAA"; CALL jani(@name); SELECT @name name;'`, then execute it.

Comment: I tried that too, but then the `var_dump()` result is either `bool(false)` (in case I use `$do->fetchObject()`) or `array(0) { }` (in case I use `$do->fetchAll()`)

@user9335240

Comment: Did you try putting that query in phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or in the MySQL client terminal app directly and see the result ?

Comment: Maybe interesting? It is one (tested) way to get  output from a mysql procedure. [MySQL retrieve variable from Stored Procedure in PHP PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749445/3184785). It is a 'little clumsy' but it does work. ;-/

Comment: @user9335240 it only worked in phpMyAdmin when I renamed the variable _name_ (since this is a reserved keyword in SQL that I forgot) to something else and used the `SELECT` statement, then the desired value returned. Despite I could make it work there, my PHP code still could not get the output value from the stored procedure, so the result stayed _NULL_ :(

Comment: @RyanVincent thank you for your comment. I tried your suggested solution too, however, it did not work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find the right solution to catch the output of my stored procedure in PHP. According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445),

> It turns out that this is a bug that has been going on for a long time... since 2005!

The source I discovered by @RyanVincent's comment also cites [this bug report through 2005-2013](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11638) and [this bug report from 2013-present](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69206).

I still needed a solution so I decided to turn my `stored procedure` into a `stored function` instead where I could easily catch the output using a simple `SELECT` statement before calling the function. This way, the return value will be selected which can be passed to PHP.

**THE CODE:**

```
// DEFINING THE FUNCTION:
$sql = '
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS jani;
    CREATE FUNCTION jani ()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(3) DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN "BBB";
    END';
$oDb->exec($sql);



// SELECTING THE RETURN VALUE OF THE FUNCTION:
$sql = 'SELECT jani();';
$do = $oDb->query($sql);



// DISPLAYING THE RESULT:
var_dump($do->fetchAll());
```

Thanks again for all the comments :) I hope this solution will help someone else spending hours on fixing their code.

Comment: It is good that you have one output so that you can just use a `function` in your circumstances. The issue arises when the processing is complex and you want more than one output. Alas, from the point of view of MySQL. Functions are different from Procedures. I am glad you solved your problem.

Comment: What kind of disadvantages do you have in mind? Like in which situations is it better to use functions instead of stored procedures and vice versa in your experience? @RyanVincent

Comment: I never mentioned disadvantages? I never mentioned about 'better' or 'worse' about using function or procedures? They both have useful 'use cases'.