# Correct way of obtaining an out parameter from a PDO Callable Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the out parameter returned after an insert call. I can't figure out how to correct my PDO syntax such that it returns the ID of the newly created section.

**connection.php**

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$db = "my_db";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$charset = "utf8";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db; charset=$charset";

try {
    $opt = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errorMessage');</script>";
}
```

**daoimpl.php**

```
function addNewSection(Section $section)
{
    //$isSuccessful = false;
    $outSectionId = 0;

    $sectionName = $section->getSectionName();

    $this->connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $sp_addNewSection = $this->connection->prepare('CALL addSection(?,@outSectionId)');
        $sp_addNewSection->bind_param('s',$sectionName);
        $sp_addNewSection->execute();

        //not sure how to do it correctly here
        $select = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT @outSectionId');
        $select->execute();
        $resultSet = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $outSectionId = $resultSet['@outSectionId'];

        $this->connection->commit();
        //$isSuccessful = true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
        $this->connection->rollback();
    }
        //return $isSuccessful;
    return $outSectionId;
}
```

**addSection** stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addSection`(`pSectionName` VARCHAR(255), OUT opSectionId INT)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO section(section_name)
VALUES(pSectionName);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO opSectionId;

SELECT opSectionId;

END
```

It is important that I obtain the out parameter section ID value back to php because I'll be adding more queries within the transaction block.

I just can't get it to work. I'm able to get the sectionId if I run / call the stored proc within MySQL Workbench but it's not working in PHP.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the pSchoolYearId parameter for? I don't see it used in the procedure anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL retrieve variable from Stored Procedure in PHP PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo)

Comment: @J2112O, I edited the description of question. I removed `pSchoolYearId`, tried running it but still can't get the output parameter `opSectionId`

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `DELIMITER` in your procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addSection`(`pSectionName` VARCHAR(255), OUT opSectionId INT) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO section(section_name) VALUES(pSectionName);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO opSectionId;
   SELECT opSectionId;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```