# Why does a mysql stored procedure return a null result in one environment and not another?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I run a live environment and a testing environment. I have a stored procedure in a MySQL database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `test`(OUT `output1` VARCHAR(5), OUT `output2` VARCHAR(36))
NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SET output1 = 'hello';
    SET output2 = 'there';
END
```

In both my live environment and test environment, I can call the stored procedure directly

```
CALL `test`(@p0, @p1);
SELECT @p0 AS `output1`, @p1 AS `output2`;
```

This returns:

```
Output1    Output2
hello      there
```

I can call the stored procedure using PDO

```
$query = "CALL test(:output1, :output2)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':output1', $output1);
$stmt->bindParam(':output2', $output2);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```

In my live environment, this returns

```
array(2) { ["output1"]=> string(5) "hello" ["output2"]=> string(5) "there" }
```

In my test environment, it returns an empty array.

Why might the two environments return different results with the same stored procedure?

Comment: Why not try a `$foo_arr = $stmt->errorInfo();` followed by `print_r($foo_arr);`? See: [errorInfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)

Comment: i was under the impression that [it's impssible to get an out parameter from a mysql stored procedure in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo/23749445#23749445) bit it seems the old bug has been finally fixed

Comment: errorinfo() returns 00000, so no failures, but no results.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Please explain what you mean by the bug having been fixed. In what direction? I'm using PHP 7.4 in both environments. From https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements example #4, I thought that I could bind an output parameter to a variable. If it is a bug, why is it working differently between environments?

Comment: Given there are sources claiming it's impossible to get an out value from mysql  due to a bug, and given your code returns an out value from mysql, the bug apparently has been fixed. That's a very simple logical conclusion. The page you linked is about pdo not mysql, and explicitly says "if a driver supports it".

Answer (score 1):

You should first decide if you want to return the values as OUT-parameters or as a result set. Your first example uses the OUT-parameters, whereas the second one expects a result set (i.e. `SELECT` in the procedure).

Usually it is better to return the values as a result set, rather than use the OUT-parameters. OUT-parameters work better when you have procedures calling other procedures.

As for the difference, do you have the function `uuid_v4` defined in both environments?

Comment: The uuid_v4 in the original question is the same in both environments. I've removed it from the original function definition.
Both functions will return results using `SELECT output1, output2;` so I can return the results as an array. I would like to know why one environment returns OUT parameters whilst the other one doesn't.

Comment: @bdbd In order to use stored procerdure's OUT parameter, you need to specify the parameter as `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php. But, instead of using OUT-parameters, use normal `SELECT` and handle the result set.

Comment: @slaasko Thanks. Even when using `PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 5` the parameter doesn't bind. Using a SELECT returns the result, and it solves the problem, but it doesn't answer the question as to why there is a difference between the environments.

Comment: @bdbd Your PHP-code dumps out the result set. Not the $output1 and $output2 variables.