# Retrieving OUT paramters from stored procedures PHP and MariaDB MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

When calling a stored procedure from PHP, the following code produces the correct results but is it possible to bind the two OUT parameters rather than holding them in @result and @id_ssn and then executing another statement to select them?

```
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("call logger(?,?,?,?,@result,@id_ssn);");
    $stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $id_log, $u, $p, $ip );

    if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
      throw new Exception("Failed to execute stored procedure logger().", 2);
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select @result, @id_ssn;");

    if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
      throw new Exception("Failed to execute query to get results of logger().", 3);
    }

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ( $stmt->num_rows == 0 ) {
      throw new Exception("No results in logger().", 4);
    }

    $stmt->bind_result($res,$id_ssn);
    $stmt->fetch();
```

When calling a stored procedure from within a stored procedure the following one line of code produces the correct result, but is it possible to retrieve the OUT parameter to a variable declared in the outer procedure rather than an @r_usr?

`call str_proc( id_mbr, '01', @r_usr );`

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747835/mysql-retrieve-variable-from-stored-procedure-in-php-pdo) has a reference to a Example 4 of a [PHP page](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) that uses the PDO layer to get the OUT parameters.  I've been using PHP and MariaDB for about two weeks now and know very little; and nothing about the PDO which I don't think I'm using, at least not referencing it in my code directly.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
This question was closed as a duplicate but the question referenced provides nothing more than the code provided in my question.  My question concerns whether or not there is a better method as the SO question and PHP page links provided bring up but do not resolve.  Unless, of course, the answer is simply that this is the best or only approach other than the PDO.

In the SO question referenced in my question that asker takes the position that if the OUT parameters must be received into user-defined variables and then a second statement executed to write them to PHP variables, he could've have just retrieved them from the database in the second statement and not included OUT parameters in the stored procedure.  I don't know much but it would appear that, although that is correct, a statement to write the user-defined variables to PHP variables is simpler than querying the table or tables again.

Then there is the PDO approach given in the aforementioned Example 4.  Is it more efficient or just easier to write?

Thus, the proposed duplicate is not a duplicate question apart from the title, which I likely should have made more specific to make it clear that it wasn't asking just how can the OUT parameters be retrieved but the right or most efficient method.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for the links.  If one is familiar with the process of coding SQL statements in the SQLite C API is there still value in the PDO?  I mean is it to make it easier for beginners or does it perform more efficiently?  Thanks.

Comment: PDO is the default extension to be used when connecting to many different DB types, including SQLite, MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres, etc. Unless you have some really good reason not to use PDO, you should be using PDO when coding in PHP. I am not sure what C API you are talking about, because PHP is not C and it has a completely different syntax and extensions. Judging by the way you are using mysqli I assumed you are only starting your PHP journey. It's best to unlearn bad practices as early as possible. You can use mysqli if you want, but why make your life harder?

Comment: Re duplicate closure. The linked answer clearly states: "*Unfortunately, MySQLi does not have any native support for output sproc parameters; one must instead output into MySQL user variables and then fetch the values using a separate SELECT statement.*" There is no functionality to bind an OUT parameter in mysqli prepared statements or PDO for that matter. Use SQL variables and then execute another SELECT to fetch that variable. What other answer are you expecting to receive?

Comment: @Dharman Are you saying that Example 4 of the PHP link provided in my question is not binding an out parameter from the stored procedure using the PDO?  It's being written to `$return_value` which looks like a PHP variable and not a MySQL user variable.  That duplicate question is nine years old.  Maybe something has been improved since that answer.  The SO question I referred to was asked eight years ago and asks the same thing about the PDO from Example 4.

Comment: I am involved in PHP development and the last time I checked PDO_MySQL still didn't have support for OUT parameter binding, despite PDO having that feature in general. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call "*for mysql it doesn't work. You have to resort to an SQL variable and an extra call.*" There are currently no plans on adding this functionality to the MySQL driver. It is supported by some other drivers though.

Comment: It looks like you tend to jump right at the code, overlooking the textual information. And promptly missing your answer. The very "example 4" explicitly states, "**If the database driver supports it**, an application may also bind parameters for output as well as input...". Ans so it's the case with the dupe link, that **directly answers** your question. Do not skip the text, it may contain your answer ;)